# how to use the function passed in different android library module in the logger class

Tags: java, android, events, logging

I have an android application, this android application has various separate android library module. Each module has a code which performs various activities related to the application like login, logout, specific activity related to application etc. Now I have created a separate android library module to log the various activities performed by the user in the application. But I don't know how to specify/pass the function name or parameter name that belong to other android library modules in logger class to just log the activities that happen in the application.So can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Did you compile dependency of other lib modules to your "logger module"?

Comment: yes i hv done but i am not getting how to pass the function /parameter in logger class to get log the activities in the modules

Comment: how to write loginlogger to extract details like number of successful attempts,number of failed attempts,total attempts etc in android application using separate android library module